# How to use the Canonicalized data by easpi in javascript

Tags: java, esapi

How i use Esapi to Canonicalize the data as suggested by veracode.

```
out.print(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(jsonObj.toJSONString()));
```

Now the data seen in console is

```
&#x7b;&quot;total&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;records&quot;&#x3a;5,&quot;rows&quot;&#x3a;&#x5b;&#x7b;&quot;id&quot;&#x3a;&quot;RLCP.NS&quot;,&quot;cell&quot;&#x3a;&#x7b;&quot;ser&quot;&#x3a;&quot;EQ&quot;,&quot;bdlt&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;e&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE&quot;,&quot;chigh&quot;&#x3a;&quot;534.7&quot;,&quot;tick&quot;&#x3a;&quot;0.05&quot;,&quot;m&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;prec&quot;&#x3a;2,&quot;W&#x5c;&#x2f;L&quot;&#x3a;null,&quot;exch&quot;&#x3a;&quot;nse_cm&quot;,&quot;tk&quot;&#x3a;&quot;2882&quot;,&quot;action&quot;&#x3a;&quot;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt2&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Buy&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Buy&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt1&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Sell&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Sell&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&quot;,&quot;rowtoken&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE2882&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;&#x3a;&quot;RLCP.NS&quot;,&quot;clow&quot;&#x3a;&quot;437.5&quot;&#x7d;&#x7d;,&#x7b;&quot;id&quot;&#x3a;&quot;SBI.NS&quot;,&quot;cell&quot;&#x3a;&#x7b;&quot;ser&quot;&#x3a;&quot;EQ&quot;,&quot;bdlt&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;e&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE&quot;,&quot;chigh&quot;&#x3a;&quot;339.8&quot;,&quot;tick&quot;&#x3a;&quot;0.05&quot;,&quot;m&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;prec&quot;&#x3a;2,&quot;W&#x5c;&#x2f;L&quot;&#x3a;null,&quot;exch&quot;&#x3a;&quot;nse_cm&quot;,&quot;tk&quot;&#x3a;&quot;3045&quot;,&quot;action&quot;&#x3a;&quot;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt2&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Buy&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Buy&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt1&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Sell&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Sell&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&quot;,&quot;rowtoken&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE3045&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;&#x3a;&quot;SBI.NS&quot;,&quot;clow&quot;&#x3a;&quot;278.1&quot;&#x7d;&#x7d;,&#x7b;&quot;id&quot;&#x3a;&quot;YESB.NS&quot;,&quot;cell&quot;&#x3a;&#x7b;&quot;ser&quot;&#x3a;&quot;EQ&quot;,&quot;bdlt&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;e&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE&quot;,&quot;chigh&quot;&#x3a;&quot;948.65&quot;,&quot;tick&quot;&#x3a;&quot;0.05&quot;,&quot;m&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;prec&quot;&#x3a;2,&quot;W&#x5c;&#x2f;L&quot;&#x3a;null,&quot;exch&quot;&#x3a;&quot;nse_cm&quot;,&quot;tk&quot;&#x3a;&quot;11915&quot;,&quot;action&quot;&#x3a;&quot;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt2&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Buy&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Buy&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt1&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Sell&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Sell&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&quot;,&quot;rowtoken&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE11915&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;&#x3a;&quot;YESB.NS&quot;,&quot;clow&quot;&#x3a;&quot;776.25&quot;&#x7d;&#x7d;,&#x7b;&quot;id&quot;&#x3a;&quot;BOB.NS&quot;,&quot;cell&quot;&#x3a;&#x7b;&quot;ser&quot;&#x3a;&quot;EQ&quot;,&quot;bdlt&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;e&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE&quot;,&quot;chigh&quot;&#x3a;&quot;212.45&quot;,&quot;tick&quot;&#x3a;&quot;0.05&quot;,&quot;m&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;prec&quot;&#x3a;2,&quot;W&#x5c;&#x2f;L&quot;&#x3a;null,&quot;exch&quot;&#x3a;&quot;nse_cm&quot;,&quot;tk&quot;&#x3a;&quot;4668&quot;,&quot;action&quot;&#x3a;&quot;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt2&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Buy&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Buy&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt1&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Sell&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Sell&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&quot;,&quot;rowtoken&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE4668&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;&#x3a;&quot;BOB.NS&quot;,&quot;clow&quot;&#x3a;&quot;173.85&quot;&#x7d;&#x7d;,&#x7b;&quot;id&quot;&#x3a;&quot;SBNK.NS&quot;,&quot;cell&quot;&#x3a;&#x7b;&quot;ser&quot;&#x3a;&quot;EQ&quot;,&quot;bdlt&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;e&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE&quot;,&quot;chigh&quot;&#x3a;&quot;128.85&quot;,&quot;tick&quot;&#x3a;&quot;0.05&quot;,&quot;m&quot;&#x3a;1,&quot;prec&quot;&#x3a;2,&quot;W&#x5c;&#x2f;L&quot;&#x3a;null,&quot;exch&quot;&#x3a;&quot;nse_cm&quot;,&quot;tk&quot;&#x3a;&quot;7179&quot;,&quot;action&quot;&#x3a;&quot;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt2&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Buy&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Buy&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&lt;button class&#x3d;&#x27;button-style-s button-alt1&#x27; onclick&#x3d;&#x27;Sell&#x28;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x27;&gt;Sell&lt;&#x5c;&#x2f;button&gt;&quot;,&quot;rowtoken&quot;&#x3a;&quot;NSE7179&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;&#x3a;&quot;SBNK.NS&quot;,&quot;clow&quot;&#x3a;&quot;105.45&quot;&#x7d;&#x7d;&#x5d;&#x7d;
```

But it renders in html as

```
{"total":1,"records":5,"rows":[{"id":"RLCP.NS","cell":{"ser":"EQ","bdlt":1,"e":"NSE","chigh":"534.7","tick":"0.05","m":1,"prec":2,"W\/L":null,"exch":"nse_cm","tk":"2882","action":"<button class='button-style-s button-alt2' onclick='Buy();'>Buy<\/button><button class='button-style-s button-alt1' onclick='Sell();'>Sell<\/button>","rowtoken":"NSE2882","ts":"RLCP.NS","clow":"437.5"}},{"id":"SBI.NS","cell":{"ser":"EQ","bdlt":1,"e":"NSE","chigh":"339.8","tick":"0.05","m":1,"prec":2,"W\/L":null,"exch":"nse_cm","tk":"3045","action":"<button class='button-style-s button-alt2' onclick='Buy();'>Buy<\/button><button class='button-style-s button-alt1' onclick='Sell();'>Sell<\/button>","rowtoken":"NSE3045","ts":"SBI.NS","clow":"278.1"}},{"id":"YESB.NS","cell":{"ser":"EQ","bdlt":1,"e":"NSE","chigh":"948.65","tick":"0.05","m":1,"prec":2,"W\/L":null,"exch":"nse_cm","tk":"11915","action":"<button class='button-style-s button-alt2' onclick='Buy();'>Buy<\/button><button class='button-style-s button-alt1' onclick='Sell();'>Sell<\/button>","rowtoken":"NSE11915","ts":"YESB.NS","clow":"776.25"}},{"id":"BOB.NS","cell":{"ser":"EQ","bdlt":1,"e":"NSE","chigh":"212.45","tick":"0.05","m":1,"prec":2,"W\/L":null,"exch":"nse_cm","tk":"4668","action":"<button class='button-style-s button-alt2' onclick='Buy();'>Buy<\/button><button class='button-style-s button-alt1' onclick='Sell();'>Sell<\/button>","rowtoken":"NSE4668","ts":"BOB.NS","clow":"173.85"}},{"id":"SBNK.NS","cell":{"ser":"EQ","bdlt":1,"e":"NSE","chigh":"128.85","tick":"0.05","m":1,"prec":2,"W\/L":null,"exch":"nse_cm","tk":"7179","action":"<button class='button-style-s button-alt2' onclick='Buy();'>Buy<\/button><button class='button-style-s button-alt1' onclick='Sell();'>Sell<\/button>","rowtoken":"NSE7179","ts":"SBNK.NS","clow":"105.45"}}]}
```

As shown, my javscript fails to understand the data and fails. What can i do to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ESAPI.encode().escapeForJavaScript() I got the following result

```
\x7B\x22mw0\x22\x3A\x22Default\x22\x7D
```

Now to change it to a format that could be understood by the java script I used following code.

```
data="\x7B\x22mw0\x22\x3A\x22Default\x22\x7D"
decodeURIComponent(data.replace(/\\x/g, '%'));
```

Return is

```
"{"mw0":"Default"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your data in accordance with how you intend the data to be used.  In this case, you have data that's intended for a javascript context, so you're going to want to use `ESAPI.encode().escapeForJavaScript()` with links to the interface [here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.java#Encoder.encodeForJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29)

If you were sending that data to be directly rendered to the page, *then* you'd use `ESAPI.encode().encodeForHTML()`.

As it currently stands however, even using the javascript escaping probably won't work because you're trying to encode the *entire* JSON object.  For this to work properly, you need to make sure that each individual data element is being escaped for the javscript context instead.

For example, the code that gets marshalled to this JSON:

```
       {
        "id": "SBNK.NS",
        "cell": {
            "ser": "EQ",
            "bdlt": 1,
            "e": "NSE",
            "chigh": "128.85",
            "tick": "0.05",
            "m": 1,
            "prec": 2,
            "W\/L": null,
            "exch": "nse_cm",
            "tk": "7179",
            "action": "<button class='button-style-s button-alt2' onclick='Buy();'>Buy<\/button><button class='button-style-s button-alt1' onclick='Sell();'>Sell<\/button>",
            "rowtoken": "NSE7179",
            "ts": "SBNK.NS",
            "clow": "105.45"
        }
```

Assuming its java code on the server, you would want to do this:

```
public void someControllerMethod(httpReq, httpResp){

     DataObject myData = somthingFromADao.getBean();
     ViewBean vBean = new vBean();

     vBean.setId(encoder.escapeForJavaScript(myData.id));
     Cell myCell = myData.getCell();
     Cell vCell = new vCell();
     vCell.setSer(encode.escapeForJavaScript(myCell.getSer()));
     // ...^^^can be done as a "populate" method or some similar pattern.
     //Marshall as JSON
}
```

The only thing in your data set that might give you some headaches appears to be the "action" field:  Its clearly trying to inject HTML to be rendered.  Veracode won't flag it, but you'll have to make sure that you're watching that vector for XSS as well.  That should be re-architected so you don't have to pass dynamically generated code as a data element.  Most XSS these days is DOM-based so as much as possible you don't want to be writing HTML in the browser.